# Better syntax highlighting in MATLAB/Octave

Tags: syntax-highlighting, matlab, octave

I'm using emacs for editing a bunch of matlab files. The only gripe that I have is that the syntax highlighting provided by `octave-mode` is pretty poor.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeM7Z.jpg) is the syntax highlighting provided by sublime text, while [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cg3x.jpg) is emacs. On the right side is `octave-mode`, on the left is `matlab-mode`.

**How can I have syntax highlighting for the keywords and numbers in emacs?**

EDIT: I just found `highlight-numbers-mode` for the numbers, the only problem left is the keywords highlighting.

Comment: As a side note (if you're into this kind of thing) you can also have semantic highlighting of identifiers with [`rainbow-identifiers-mode`](https://github.com/Fanael/rainbow-identifiers).

Answer (score 2):

`octave-mode` does have some keywords [(see source)](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/progmodes/octave.el). Even so, you can [add your own](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AddKeywords):

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'octave-mode
                        '(("\\<load\\>". font-lock-keyword-face)                                                                                                                           
                          ("\\<clear\\>". font-lock-keyword-face)))
```